# Redux Thunk : Action must be plain object

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-thunk

I have gone through most of the posts here about problems of this nature but I still have no luck. This is what my action looks like, it is the same example from the redux-thunk npm readme file:

```
const INCREMENT_COUNTER = 'INCREMENT_COUNTER';

function increment() {
  return {
    type: INCREMENT_COUNTER
  };
}

function incrementAsync() {
  return dispatch => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      // Yay! Can invoke sync or async actions with `dispatch`
      dispatch(increment());
    }, 1000);
  };
}
```

Store is set up as below and passed to the provider:

```
export default createStore(
  rootReducer,
  applyMiddleware(thunk)
);

<Provider store={store}>
```

Also tried using compose:

```
export default compose(
  applyMiddleware(thunk)
)(createStore)(combineReducers({ ... }));
```

The incrementAsync is dispatched from a connected component as below:

```
this.props.dispatch(incrementAsync);
```

I still get `Uncaught Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.`

NPM versions:

```
"react": "^16.3.2", 
"react-dom": "^16.3.2", 
"react-redux": "^5.0.7",
"react-router-dom": "^4.2.2", 
"redux": "^4.0.0", 
"redux-thunk": "^2.2.0"
```

Is there anything that I am not setting up correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it should be `this.props.dispatch(incrementAsync());`
instead of `this.props.dispatch(incrementAsync);`

Comment: Thank you! Was ripping my hair out for hours on this!

Answer (score 0):

At connector component

```
this.props.dispatch(incrementAsync)
```

replace with

```
this.props.incrementAsync();
```

and bind incrementAsync function in connection like

```
connnect(null, { incrementAsync  }) (Component)
```